# A question about the exact formula for the collector current

Tags: transistors, current, bjt, solid-state-devices

Regarding the collector current Ic equation in the below figure:

[image]

The above figure tells:

Ic = Is * (exp(Vbe/Ut)-1)

But I thought it should be:

Ic = **α** * Is * (exp(Vbe/Ut)-1) + **Icbo**

1-) Is **α** and **Icbo** neglected in the figure?

2-) Is the reverse saturation current ***Is*** the reverse saturation current between the base-emitter junction? Is ***Is*** that the same thing called Ieo in some texts?

Comment: I'm not familiar with \$I_{EO}\$, itself. Is it just another name for \$I_{EBO}\$? In any case, I recommend studying [Level 1 BJT Model](http://www.analog-innovations.com/SED/BipolarTransistor_FromPSPCREF.pdf). Pretty much all the details are there for you. (I am assuming you mean 'area' when you write \$a\$. You will see that term in the above document.) I find plotting these things on a log chart helps a great deal in understanding the factors, though. For example, \$I_S\$ is just what you get at the y-axis when you apply a ruler to the flat part in region II curve of the BJT operating mode.

Comment: No that is alpha

Comment: Okay. Then I recommend reading the document I gave you. All answers are in there and detailed well. Start with the section on DC operation.

Comment: In that document there is not a single term called "reverse saturation current" The terminology is horrible.

Comment: Sorry, then. I started to consider what I wanted to write about this, because what you wrote isn't consistent with the way I think of things. This means we'd be at cross-purposes until we'd established mutual foundations we understood and agreed to share. And then we could move forward. Then I just gave up. Too much work establishing terms. I apologize for my lack of energy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per Ebers–Moll Model of an NPN transistor:

$$I_E = I_{ES} (e^{V_{BE}/V_T} -1) -\alpha_RI_{CS}(e^{V_{BC}/V_T}-1)$$
$$I_C = \alpha_FI_{ES} (e^{V_{BE}/V_T} -1) -I_{CS}(e^{V_{BC}/V_T}-1)$$
where:

\$ I_{ES}\$ = reverse saturation current of Base-Emitter Junction.

\$ \alpha_R\$ = reverse current gain

\$ \alpha_F\$ = foward current gain

\$ I_{CS}\$ =  reverse saturation current of Base-Collector Junction.

Approximated Ebers-Moll Models look like:
$$I_E \approx I_{ES} (e^{V_{BE}/V_T} -1) $$
$$I_C \approx \alpha_FI_{ES} (e^{V_{BE}/V_T} -1) $$
which satisfies the normal convention: \$ I_C = \alpha_F I_E \$

Therefore, whatever source you took the figure from, By \$ I_S \$ they mean, \$ \alpha_F I_{ES} \$.

If you are looking for where is \$ I_{CBO} \$, it is there in the original equation of \$ I_C \$ , the term --> \$-I_{CS}(e^{V_{BC}/V_T}-1) \$ is nothing but equals to \$ + I_{CBO}\$.

From the original Ebers-Moll Model equations, you can see that  even \$ I_C = \alpha_F I_E + I_{CBO} \$  is an approximation, as it neglects the second term in the expression for \$I_E\$.